# Getting data from GAP in a Python program - Sage or without Sage?

Tags: python, sage, gap-system

I have a Python parser that can read from and write to static JSON files (containing JSON objects that map to Python dicts) on my local machine.  The properties of these objects related to finite group objects in the [GAP Small Groups Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html).  Is there a way I can get data from GAP so that I can update the object info in these JSON files?  I have GAP on the machine.

Obviously I can use [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), which has a shell that recognises Python, but I don't have it on my system and I just don't have the space.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Is http://gap-system.github.io/json/ of any help? This package will be included in GAP 4.7.7 distrubution, which is coming soon.

Comment: I have manged to upload the JSON files to my folders in Sage Math Cloud.  So I guess I can just upload the script as well and run the script in a Sage session within a terminal session in the cloud and update the file that way.